# Trigger event in another ng-view after $location.path() has changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to trigger an alert in another view after $location.path() has changed the ng-view (without using $rootScope).

In my controller trigger event I have :

```
$location.path('/');
myService.setAlert("My alert");
```

My service passes the "message" and $broadcast an event

```
myService.broadcastAlert = function(){
  $rootScope.$broadcast('alertChanged');
};

myService.setAlert = function(message){
  myService.alert = message;
  rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    myService.broadcastAlert();
  });
}
```

My other view's controller receives an alert

```
$scope.$on('alertChanged', function(){
  console.log("New Alert is triggered");
});
```

The problem here is the rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess') continues to run after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need the deregistration:

```
myService.setAlert = function(message){
  myService.alert = message;
  var deregister = rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    myService.broadcastAlert();
    deregister();
  });
};
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks ! But I'm not quite sure I understand how it works, could you tell me where I could read more on the deregister function ?

Comment: Sure: the docs for `Scope` for [1.1.5](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope) or [latest](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope). Check the return value of the `$on` method. Actually it is not a big deal: `$on()` returns a deregistration function. When called, it simply deregisters the listener.

Comment: This still uses rootScope, doesn't it?

Comment: It uses the `$rootScope`, but addresses the *real* problem that was that the listener was not deregistered when the controller was stopped.